# Is my logic regarding sorted linked list implementation wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been practicing to implement a sorted (auto-update during operations) linked list in Python (normally people use C++ for implementing).

Currently, I have completed the below code (in the file definitions.py):

```py
class LinkedListException(Exception):
    pass


class Node:
    def __init__(self, content=None):
        self.content = content
        self.adjacent = None


class SortedLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def retrieve(self, entry):
        tmp = self.head
        while tmp is not None:
            if tmp.content == entry:
                return tmp
            tmp = tmp.adjacent
        raise LinkedListException(f"Entry {entry} not found.")

    def append(self, entry):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(entry)
            return
        tmp = self.head
        while tmp.adjacent is not None:
            if tmp.content > entry:
                print("p", tmp.content)
                break
            tmp = tmp.adjacent
        n = Node(entry)
        tmp.adjacent = n
        n.adjacent = None
```

And in main.py:

```py
from sortedLinkedLists.definitions import SortedLinkedList


def main():
    obj = SortedLinkedList()
    obj.append(1)
    obj.append(3)
    obj.append(2)
    print(obj.head.content)
    print(obj.head.adjacent.content)
    print(obj.head.adjacent.adjacent.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(Description for line 1: I used pycharm, and my project name is `sortedLinkedLists`)

But I just got:

```
1
3
2
```

in the original order that I appended them.

I wished to auto-sort the list during insertion, so there must be something wrong.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. I tried other test cases and it just appended all of the test cases in order without actually sorting them. Currently, this is identical to a linked list!

Comment: You have never implemented any auto-sorting  here.

Comment: @dmitryro So... How do I implement it? Any advice?

Comment: You can use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/heapq.html) or other priority queue approaches for sorted lists.

Comment: @dmitryro OP wants to implement sorting themselves, not using a library. @ian-chiang You need to rethink your `append` function using pen-and-paper. I would also advise you to rename it to `insert` since append isn't the right term to use for a sorted insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some problem with the logic in append:

here you go:

```
def append(self, entry):
        n=Node(entry)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = n
            return
        if self.head.content > entry:
            self.head, n.adjacent = n, self.head
            return
        
        tmp=self.head
        while tmp.adjacent and tmp.adjacent.content < entry:
            tmp=tmp.adjacent
        n.adjacent = tmp.adjacent
        tmp.adjacent = n
```